# Move stepper motor in triomotion

Tags: basic

I'm working with a Trio Motion MC405 at work and no matter what I do, I can't get the axis to move.

```
WDOG = OFF

BASE(0)
ATYPE = 43 'STEPPER
SPEED = 5000
ACCEL = 100000
DECEL = 150000
SERVO = ON;

WDOG = ON
MOVE(30) AXIS(0)
```

Has anyone played with Motion Perfect V3.3, I'd appreciate any help.